# Can't find a way to keep my keyboard input working on a Javascript Calculator with Keyboard Events

Tags: javascript, html, ascii, calculator, keyboard-events

I'm making a simple calculator.

I've added an event listener and a `console.log()` to print my event and see what happens, but I've noticed that it only fires when I click on the calculator again.

```js
// stores the results of the equations
let runningTotal = 0;  
// displays it's value on the screen
let buffer = "0"; 
// stores the last inputed operator (+,-,*,/)
let previousOperator; 

const screen = document.querySelector('.screen');

function inputKeys(value){
    if(isNaN(value)){
        handleSymbol(value);
    } else {
        handleNumber(value);
    }

    screen.innerText = buffer;
}

function handleSymbol(symbol){
    switch (symbol) {
        case 'C':
            buffer = '0';
            runningTotal = 0;
            break;
        case '=':
            if(previousOperator === null) return;
            
            flushOperation(parseFloat(buffer));
            previousOperator = null;
            buffer = runningTotal;
            runningTotal = 0;
            
            break;
        case '←':
            if(buffer.length === 1)
                buffer = '0';
            else
                buffer = buffer.toString(0, buffer.length - 1)
                
            break;
        case '+':
        case '−':
        case '×':
        case '÷':
            handleMath(symbol);
            break;
        case '.':
            handleDecimal(symbol);
            break;
    }
}

function handleNumber(numberString){
    if(buffer === "0"){
        buffer = numberString;
    } else {
        buffer += numberString;
    }
}

function handleDecimal(symbol) {
    if(!buffer.includes(symbol)){
        buffer += symbol;
    } else {
        return;
    }
}

function handleMath(symbol){
    if(buffer === '0') return; 

    const floatBuffer = parseFloat(buffer);

    if(runningTotal === 0){
        runningTotal = floatBuffer;
    } else {
        flushOperation(floatBuffer);
    }
    previousOperator = symbol;
    buffer = '0';
}

function flushOperation(floatBuffer) {
    if(previousOperator === '+'){
        runningTotal += floatBuffer;
    } else if(previousOperator === '−'){
        runningTotal -= floatBuffer;
    } else if(previousOperator === '×'){
        runningTotal *= floatBuffer;
    } else if(previousOperator === '÷'){
        runningTotal /= floatBuffer;
    }
}

function init(){
    document.querySelector('.calc-buttons').addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
        console.log(event);
    })
    document.querySelector('.calc-buttons').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        inputKeys(event.target.innerText);
    })
}

init();
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <section class="screen">0</section>

  <section class="calc-buttons">

    <div class=calc-button-row>
      <button class="calc-button double">
          C
      </button>
      <button class="calc-button">
          &larr;
      </button>
      <button class=" calc-button">
          &divide;
      </button>

    </div>

      <div class="calc-button-row">
        <button class="calc-button">
            7
        </button>
        <button class="calc-button">
            8
        </button>
        <button class="calc-button">
            9
        </button>
        <button class="calc-button">
            &times;
        </button>
      </div>

      <div class="calc-button-row">
        <button class="calc-button">
            4
        </button>
        <button class="calc-button">
            5
        </button>
        <button class="calc-button">
            6
        </button>
        <button class="calc-button">
            &minus;
        </button>
      </div>

      <div class="calc-button-row">
        <button class="calc-button">
            1
        </button>
        <button class="calc-button">
            2
        </button>
        <button class="calc-button">
            3
        </button>
        <button class="calc-button">
            &plus;
        </button>
      </div>

      <div class="calc-button-row">
        <button class="calc-button double">
            0
        </button>
        <button class="calc-button">
            .
        </button>
        <button class="calc-button">
            &equals;
        </button>
      </div>

  </section>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** Just noticed that my *'case '←''* is not working either.

Comment: Can you please add your script.js so we can see how you're adding the event handlers?

Comment: I'm sorry, i was editing the script @PaulProgrammer.
Should be done now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding the `keydown` listener on the calculator. That's why you have to click on the calculator first before using the key input. You have to focus on the element first.

Instead, add the `keydown` listener on the `document`. Here's an example:

```js
let runningTotal = 0; //stores the results of the equations
let buffer = "0"; //displays it's value on the screen
let previousOperator; //stores the last inputed operator (+,-,*,/)

const screen = document.querySelector('.screen');

function inputKeys(value) {

  if (isNaN(value))
    handleSymbol(value);
  else
    handleNumber(value);

  screen.innerText = buffer;
}

function handleSymbol(symbol) {
  switch (symbol) {
    case 'C':
      buffer = '0';
      runningTotal = 0;
      break;
    case '=':
      if (previousOperator === null) {
        return
      }
      flushOperation(parseFloat(buffer));
      previousOperator = null;
      buffer = runningTotal;
      runningTotal = 0;
      break;
    case '←':
      if (buffer.length === 1)
        buffer = '0';
      else
        buffer = buffer.toString(0, buffer.length - 1)
      break;
    case '+':
    case '−':
    case '×':
    case '÷':
      handleMath(symbol);
      break;
    case '.':
      handleDecimal(symbol);
      break;
  }
}

function handleNumber(numberString) {
  if (buffer === "0") {
    buffer = numberString;
  } else {
    buffer += numberString;
  }
}

function handleDecimal(symbol) {
  if (!buffer.includes(symbol)) {
    buffer += symbol;
  } else {
    return;
  }
}

function handleMath(symbol) {
  if (buffer === '0') {
    return;
  }
  const floatBuffer = parseFloat(buffer);

  if (runningTotal === 0) {
    runningTotal = floatBuffer;
  } else {
    flushOperation(floatBuffer);
  }
  previousOperator = symbol;
  buffer = '0';
}

function flushOperation(floatBuffer) {
  if (previousOperator === '+') {
    runningTotal += floatBuffer;
  } else if (previousOperator === '−') {
    runningTotal -= floatBuffer;
  } else if (previousOperator === '×') {
    runningTotal *= floatBuffer;
  } else if (previousOperator === '÷') {
    runningTotal /= floatBuffer;
  }
}

function init() {

  document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    inputKeys(event.key)
  })
  document.querySelector('.calc-buttons').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    inputKeys(event.target.innerText);
  })
}
init();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>CALCULADORA DO NUNES</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="wrapper">

    <section class="screen">0</section>
    <section class="calc-buttons">
      <div class=calc-button-row>
        <button class="calc-button double">
                    C
                </button>
        <button class="calc-button">
                    &larr;
                </button>
        <button class=" calc-button">
                    &divide;
                </button>

      </div>

      <div class="calc-button-row">
        <button class="calc-button">
                    7
                </button>
        <button class="calc-button">
                    8
                </button>
        <button class="calc-button">
                    9
                </button>
        <button class="calc-button">
                    &times;
                </button>
      </div>

      <div class="calc-button-row">
        <button class="calc-button">
                    4
                </button>
        <button class="calc-button">
                    5
                </button>
        <button class="calc-button">
                    6
                </button>
        <button class="calc-button">
                    &minus;
                </button>
      </div>

      <div class="calc-button-row">
        <button class="calc-button">
                    1
                </button>
        <button class="calc-button">
                    2
                </button>
        <button class="calc-button">
                    3
                </button>
        <button class="calc-button">
                    &plus;
                </button>
      </div>

      <div class="calc-button-row">
        <button class="calc-button double">
                    0
                </button>
        <button class="calc-button">
                    .
                </button>
        <button class="calc-button">
                    &equals;
                </button>
      </div>
    </section>

  </div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is first clue for you. Try use `slice` for `case '←'`. Just `console.log(buffer);` before slice and after to check your result.